# How to implement incoming video-call notification

Tags: cordova, angular7, onesignal, opentok, ionic4

I am developing an Ionic 4 app that implements video-call using OpenTok.

I got the app working but I don't know how to receive incoming call notification and show incoming call page such as FaceTime like this page:

[image]

I tried using OneSignal to send notification then in "handleNotificationReceived()" I will open the a page in my app to mimic 
incoming call page, but when the app is closed, "handleNotificationReceived()" will not fire?

how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You would need to use [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) on iOS to invoke the native system UI. For reference, you can check out the [OpenTok CallKit](https://github.com/opentok/callkit) repo.

We don't have any samples of using it with Ionic or Cordova, but you can write your own bridge using Cordova and expose the functionality to the JavaScript/TypeScript layer.